# Bug after removing white space: JavaScript

Tags: javascript, web-services, validation

I have a website coded in JavaScript. However, whenever a user tried to register, if they left an extra white space after the confirmation email, there would be an error saying the email and confirmation email do not match. I tried to fix this using the trim() method and now I don't get the error. But if the user types in an email, the user still gets to register even if the confirmation email is different. For example: jdoe@email.com and jdoe2@email.com both are being treated as equal when they shouldn't be. Here is my code:

```
if(isBlank(document.forms.mainForm.confirmEmail.value)) {
  alert("Please confirm the bill to E-mail address.");
  document.getElementById("confirmEmail").style.color = "red";
  blackText=document.getElementById("confirmEmail");
  document.forms.mainForm.confirmEmail.focus();
  return false;
 }

 else if(!isBlank(document.forms.mainForm.confirmEmail.value))
  {
      var checkConfirm = document.forms.mainForm.confirmEmail.value;
      var emailConfirmTrim = checkConfirm.trim();
      return emailConfirmTrim;
    }

    else{
       if(emailConfirmTrim != document.forms.mainForm.email.value) {
       alert("The confirm E-mail address does not match the E-mail address.");
       document.getElementById("confirmEmail").style.color = "red";
       blackText=document.getElementById("confirmEmail");
       document.forms.mainForm.confirmEmail.focus();
       return false;
                     }
           }
```

I just want to remove the trailing white space from the confirmation email so that if the email and confirmation are the same, the user can register. Where did I go wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: `' hello '.replace(/\s/g, ''); //'hello'`

Comment: In the second `if` block where are you checking if the email and confirm emails are same?

Comment: You are assigning a value to `emailConfirmTrim` in the seconds block, but are testing it in the third block. It will never be set in the third block.

Comment: Also, you are calling `document.getElementById' multiple times for the same element...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you really need the second if block, you are not doing any check to see actually if the confirm email is same as email. Your code will never go to the third if block. You may re-write your code this way:

```
if(isBlank(document.forms.mainForm.confirmEmail.value)) {
  alert("Please confirm the bill to E-mail address.");
  document.getElementById("confirmEmail").style.color = "red";
  blackText=document.getElementById("confirmEmail");
  document.forms.mainForm.confirmEmail.focus();
  return false;
 }                
 //else if(!isBlank(document.forms.mainForm.confirmEmail.value))
 // {
 //     var checkConfirm = document.forms.mainForm.confirmEmail.value;
 //     var emailConfirmTrim = checkConfirm.trim();
 //     return emailConfirmTrim;
 //   }
 else if(document.forms.mainForm.confirmEmail.value.trim() != document.forms.mainForm.email.value) {
       alert("The confirm E-mail address does not match the E-mail address.");
       document.getElementById("confirmEmail").style.color = "red";
       blackText=document.getElementById("confirmEmail");
       document.forms.mainForm.confirmEmail.focus();
       return false;
                     }
 else
       return true;
```

Answer (score 0):

Refactored code, untested, but will give you something to start with.

```
function getEmail() {
  //Get the elements of the input fields
  var email1 = document.forms.mainForm.email;
  var email2 = document.forms.mainForm.confirmEmail;

  // Trim the values
  email1.value = email1.value.trim();
  email2.value = email2.value.trim();

  if (!email1.value) {
    alert("Please enter bill to E-mail address.");
    email1.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (!email2.value) {
    alert("Please confirm the bill to E-mail address.");
    email2.style.color = "red";
    email2.focus();
    return false;
  }

  if (email1.value != email2.value) {
    alert("The confirm E-mail address does not match the E-mail address.");
    email2.focus();
    return false;
  }

  // Return the email adress
  return email1.value;
}
```